# how to call Non-static method from Unity Android Plugin?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, plugins, aar

i want use this java code to get uri data in unity
i write this script code to call this method , but not work

*java

```
public String GetUri(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri intentData = intent.getData();
    return intentData.getQueryParameter("token");
}
```

*c#

```
TextShow.text += ajc.Call<string>("GetUri");
```

After many tests , i find only static method can call in unity

like this

*java

```
public static String DoSthInAndroid3()
{
    return "33333";
}
```

*c#

```
TextShow.text += ajc.Call<string>("DoSthInAndroid3");
```

i try Non-static method , but not work

```
public String DoSthInAndroid3()
{
    return "33333";
}

TextShow.text += ajc.Call<string>("DoSthInAndroid3");
```

how to use android Plugin to get the uri data?
the getIntent() seem cant call in static method , how do i get it ?

*------------update-----------------*

java

```
package com.s.mylibrary;
import android.net.Uri;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
public class AndroidPlugin extends UnityPlayerActivity {
    public static String GetString(){
        return"TestThisPlugin";
    }

    public String GetUri(){
        Uri intentData = getIntent().getData();
        return intentData.getQueryParameter("token");
    }
}
```

c#

```
void GetAndroidUri()
{
    var ajc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.s.mylibrary.AndroidPlugin"); //(1)
    TextShow.text += ajc.CallStatic<string>("GetString");
    TextShow.text += ajc.CallStatic<string>("GetUri");
    TextShow.text += ajc.Call<string>("GetUri");
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="justlovepaohuzi" android:host="hmok" android:pathPrefix="/UserToekn"/>
      </intent-filter>
```

html

```
        <a href="justlovepaohuzi://hmok/UserToekn/?token=123456999"> Open3 </a>
```

*-----------------update---------------*

i fix method name and try new Print code, i find i still can't get non-static method , not have error message , but still different from expectation

java

```
package com.s.mylibrary;
import android.net.Uri;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;
public class AP extends UnityPlayerActivity{
    public static String GetString(){
        return "TestThisAP";
    }
    public String GetString2(){
        return "AAAAAA";
    }
    public String GetUri(){
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        return uri.getQueryParameter("token")+"XDDX";
    }
}
```

c#

```
void GetAndroidUri()
{
    var ajc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.s.mylibrary.AP");
    TextShow.text += ajc.CallStatic<string>("GetString");
    TextShow.text += ajc.Call<string>("GetString2");
    TextShow.text += ajc.Call<string>("GetUri");
    TextShow.text += "Last";
}
```

relult string

expected
"TestThisAPAAAAAA(token)XDDXLast"

relult
"TestThisAPLast"

Comment: I am adding more details. thank

Comment: Edit is completed

Comment: would getting the `AndroidJavaObject` instead of `AndroidJavaClass` be the answer?

Comment: ok im update at the bottom

Comment: i find i use wrong name , i try it fix

Comment: @palebone After several tests, I found that I didn't know how to use AndroidJavaObject , ro meybe AndroidJavaObject and AndroidJavaClass are no different?