# Call non-static methods on custom Unity Android Plugins

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, plugins

I'm trying to understand how to build my own Android plugins for Android.

I achieve to call static methods on my Java class (the one created on AndroidStudio), but I really CAN'T call non-static methods.

I check those links:

- https://answers.unity.com/questions/884503/cant-call-non-static-method-in-androidjavaclass.html
- http://leoncvlt.com/blog/a-primer-on-android-plugin-development-in-unity/
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/1327186/how-to-get-intent-data-for-unity-to-use.html
- [how to call Non-static method from Unity Android Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367035/how-to-call-non-static-method-from-unity-android-plugin)

But none works.

I'm trying to get the call from a button from Unity like:

```
AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = UnityPlayer.Get<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
currentActivity.Call("SayHi");
```

And my activity on Android looks like:

```
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "LibraryTest";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "Created!");
    }

    public void SayHi()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "HI_");
    }
}
```

My ADB is throwing this message:
[image]

I've also tried calling instead of UnityPlayer call it like:

```
AndroidJavaClass pluginClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.eric.librarytest.MainActivity");
```

**EDIT:** 
This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.eric.librarytest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="24"
        android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.eric.librarytest.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But doesn't work either for non-static methods, it works only for static methods if I do `pluginClass.CallStatic("")`, any idea?

**EDIT 2:**

- Taras Leskiv suggest to change UnityPlayer.Get to
  UnityPlayer.GetStatic, but then i get the follow error:

  error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='SayHi' signature='()V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;
- Proguard is not active.

Comment: Can you add your AndroidManifest.xml? Do you have the MainActivity inside?

Comment: @JeanLuc added to the post, and yes, it is inside as you can see :(

Comment: Is it actually your activity returned? If so _Unity_ might not know about that type and thinks it's an `Activity`. So you might need to cast it somehow.

Comment: @tynn that was Jean Bouvattier answer, but It doesn't explain how to achieve this cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was correct, the problem was the Project structure.

My Project was like:

```
Assets
├── Plugins
│   ├── classes.jar
```

And should be like:

```
Assets
├── Plugins
│   ├── Android
│   │   ├── classes.jar
```

Was obvius (not for me) cause the error spam the message that could not find the signature, so the software can't read those classes.

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing this:

```
AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = UnityPlayer.Get<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
currentActivity.Call("SayHi");
```

It doesn't work because the `currentActivity` field is static, what you should do is:

```
AndroidJavaClass UnityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = UnityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
currentActivity.Call("SayHi");
```

Notice the **UnityPlayer.GetStatic** part

Here is other convenience snippet from one of my plugins:

```
    static AndroidJavaObject _activity;

    public static AndroidJavaObject Activity
    {
        get
        {
            if (_activity == null)
            {
                var unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass(C.ComUnity3DPlayerUnityPlayer);
                _activity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
            }
            return _activity;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then I get the following error:  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='SayHi' signature='()V' in class Ljava.lang.Object; :(

Comment: Okay, that's the next error, maybe also check if you have proguad enabled as it can obfuscate the java code on build

Comment: No, proguard is disabled cause I don't have proguard directory, what else could be?

Comment: I'm also using app-debug.aar instead of release, to be sure that no shrink is done by Proguard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has to do with java inheritence : your currentActivity AndroidJavaObject is of class `com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer`  but this class does not have `SayHi` method, you should cast your object to `MainActivity` before calling your method.

Comment: But MainActivity is also an AndroidJavaClass, how would you do it? Can you post an example please?

Comment: I cannot help you more now, but this link will probably help you : http://devua.co/2016/07/30/type-casting-androidjavaobject-in-unity-from-c/

Comment: I've tried the link but doesn't work, maybe I'm doing something wrong with the cast? o.O

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is declare your own static context in activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "LibraryTest";
    public static Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        Log.d(TAG, "Created!");
    }

    public void SayHi()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "HI_");
    }
}
```

And then just call any non-static method from C# like this:

```
public static void AndroidCallFunction()
{
    using (AndroidJavaClass javaClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.example.eric.librarytest.MainActivity"))
    {
        using (AndroidJavaObject activity = javaClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("mContext"))
        {
            activity.Call("SayHi");
        }
    }
}
```

There is **NO** other methods to call methods directly from java code. You can implement your own messaging system using AndroidJavaProxy and Broadcast commands without even activity at all, but it is another question.

Comment: This approach (static context fields) causes memory leak.

Comment: yes, but if there is too much static fields, this made is for undrestanding how ajo works

Comment: A static reference is not an option at all. First you don't know how many of these activities end up in the stack. If you really need to do it, make sure to clean up after yourself in `onDestroy`.

Comment: You have only 1 activity which implements unity player, for another things (e.g. services, another activities) you can always use broadcasts. This is very simple and classic solution

Comment: sorry for the late reply @NikolayGonza, but with your code, activity is Null :(

Comment: activity variable I mean*

Comment: did you put your activity in plugins folder? this is 100% working code, so i think there is another problem