# Cannot find the UnityPlayerActivity class inside com.unity3d.player

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, plugins

I'm trying to create an Android plugin for my Unity game. I have watched a lot of tutorials (most of them are outdated based on eclipse) and have read the documentation also. I'm using Unity 2019.3.0f6. I want to extend my main activity in Android Studio project with UnityPlayerActivity

[image]

I don't understand what does the ending lines mean "`Locate the file, and add classes.jar to the classpath Unity uses to compile the new Activity. Compile your Activity source file and package it into a JAR or AAR package, then copy it into your Project folder`"

I understand UnityPlayerActivity does not exist in the classes.jar at PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Variations/mono or il2cpp/Development or Release/Classes/ and so I can't import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity; I can only import UnityPlayer and IUnityPlayerLifecycleEvents. I am also interested to understand what is the UnityPlayer class and IUnityPlayerLifecycleEvents in this context.

[image]

But the UnityPlayerActivity.java is available at C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\src\com\unity3d\player

How do I add it in the Unity3d library or classes.jar. Or even import it to extend my mainactivity. I don't understand what am I doing wrong here. 
I am using Android Studio, although I am new to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry, make android plugins for unity could be a little bit messy at the start, even more if you don't have any experience with Android!

Some tips:

- Project directory structure should be: `Assets/Plugins/Android` (it's
  important, I've been struggling for this stupidity [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383055/call-non-static-methods-on-custom-unity-android-plugins))
- Insert `classes.jar` in AndroidStudio project in `app/libs`.
- Insert external dependencies (if you are using it) like
  "support-v4-24.1.1" into `Android/libs`

To create plugins on AndroidStudio you need to create a library (this steps is to create it from an activity):

- On graddle remove ID line
- On the same file, change `.implementation` to `.library`

To recompile the plugin do the follow:

1. Rebuild AndroidStudio solution
2. Go to AndroidStudio solution...`app\build\outputs\aar` get the `.aar`
   file
3. Copy and paste it, change the extension from `.aar` to `.zip` or `.rar`
4. Open the modified file and extract 2 items:

   - `classes.jar` (this is another classes.jar, not the same stored in app/libs in your AndroidStudio project)
   - `AndroidManifest.xml`
5. Copy those files into Unity project in `Assets/Plugins/Android`
   (remember, project directory structure is important!)

You can download the `classes.jar` file (the first one) from my [Utility_Repo](https://github.com/EricBatlle/SimpleUnityUtils/tree/master/Assets/Simple_AndroidBridge/Utils_AndroidBridge) or from the path you name it `D:\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\mono\Development\Classes\classes.jar`.

Comment: I understand what you are explaining but my question is why isn't the UnityPlayerActivity class available directly into my classes.jar .../PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Variations/mono/Development/Classes/

Comment: I just now read this article too. Looks good http://eppz.eu/blog/unity-android-plugin-tutorial-1/

Comment: What i want to achieve is, open an existing android activity specifically implement this project as a plugin 
 https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers so that i can give my unity game user some whatsapp stickers at runtime. I know this sounds very ambitious but can you give me some direction how should i approach my goal.

Comment: you don't need to remove AndroidManifest.xml from the final aar, just the classess.jar to avoid duplicates, the AndroidManifest.xml will merge with the custom one from unity. it's even more clean to have the permissions related to your aar file stay where they belong for readability

Answer (score 3):

I've got into the same situation, and after some search I've found that you should [take that class from elsewhere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.html#ExtendingUnityPlayerActivity) and simply copy it into your project. On my machine the class is in `"...path-to-unity-installation...\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Source\com\unity3d\player"`.

I think that the new approach that sidesteps using `UnityPlayerActivity` is totally worth attention, though.

Comment: Ah so the UnityPlayerActivity is separate from classes.jar now.  That's annoying.  I wonder why they changed that?

Answer (score 2):

There is a really great tutorial and accompanying youtube video on how to make native Android plugins and incorporate in Unity 3D.

http://www.cwgtech.com/using-android-webview-to-display-a-webpage-on-top-of-the-unity-app-view/

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new Module, eg: name it "UnityActivity".
2. Add classes.jar which can be found in unity install folder as Dependences in the method of "CompileOnly"
3. Add the Source Code of "UnityPlayerActivity" in to module of UnityActivity.
4. Add the new Module as Dependences to "Your Module" in the method of "CompileOnly"

Now you can create your CustomActivity extends from UnityPlayerActivity. and build into *.aar.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to mock the dependency `com.unity3d.player`. In Android Studio:

- Create a new project (`MyUnityPlayerActivity`) with "no activity".
- From `File/New/New Module`, create new Module (`Player`) with package name `com.unity3d.player`.

Apply these for "**both**" modules (`app` and `player`):

- Clean-up any non-library references (icons, themes,...etc.) from `AndroidManifest.xml`.
- Delete everything under the folder `res` except `res/values/strings.xml`.
- In `build.gradle` of the module:

  - Replace `id 'com.android.application'` with `id 'com.android.library'`.
  - Delete the line `applicationId "..."`.
  - Delete all lines related with tests.
  - Delete all dependencies.
  - Add local Unity installation dependency as "compile only" (so that it is not included in build).

```js
dependencies {
    compileOnly files('C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.32f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Variations/mono/Release/Classes/classes.jar)
}
```

In module `player`:

- Copy `UnityPlayerActivity.java` from `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\src\com\unity3d\player\` to `/player/java/com.unity3d.player`.

In module `app`:

- In `build.gradle` of module `MyUnityPlayerActivity` add compile only dependency to the module `player` we just created.

```js
dependencies {
    compileOnly files('C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.4.32f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Variations/mono/Release/Classes/classes.jar)
    compileOnly project(':player')
}
```

- Create new class `MyUnityPlayerActivity`.

```cs
package com.mycompany.myapplication.player;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity;

public class MyUnityPlayerActivity extends UnityPlayerActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "Unity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "Running MyUnityPlayerActivity.");
    }
}
```

It should be good to go.